# What is the significance of finding quark-antiquark pairs in hadrons?

Tags: standard-model, quantum-chromodynamics, quarks, confinement, hadron-dynamics

What is the significance of finding quark-antiquark pairs in hadrons?  Does is have any effect, and hypothetically, could you pull the 3 quarks in a hadron apart so they formed 3 mesons?

Comment: Baryons do not contain an antiquark, so unless I misunderstood you, your premises seem incorrect. So no, it is not possible to pull a baryon apart and construct mesons out of its components. You could certainly collide it with an anti-baryon or a meson to have the quarks recombine and produce a certain number of mesons and baryons, but two conditions must hold: (1) color charge conservation, which is believed to be a fundamental law of nature (2) all the incoming and outgoing particles must be color-neutral because of confinement.

Comment: @dmckee agree, good point, but certainly not clear from OP's question.

Comment: @dmckee You have quark anti-quark pairs inside photons! Reading assignment (with all due respect): Vector Meson Dominance.

Comment: @JEB Hmmm ... I think that my comment reads rather more abrasively than I meant it, so fair call. I'm afraid that I'm sometimes over sensitive about unqualified statement on the quark-content of baryons. Deleting the offending comment.

Comment: @dmckee I blame $\alpha_s$. It's too big. I mean Willis Lamb showed there are positrons inside a hydrogen atom, but no one's ever too concerned about them.

Answer (score 1):

Your putative logical opposites are not as incompatible as you are imagining. Through the magic of the Dirac equations involved in QCD, the gluons, that *must* be in the hadron to bind the quarks together, split into quark-antiquark pairs all the time.

So, *even if* you did not "have" quark antiquark pairs in the hadron, pulling  the three quarks apart will increase the effective intensity of the gluon field precipitously (think of them as 3 rubber bands joined together), and it would ["break down" to quark antiquark pairs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pair_production) (in some analogy of a hyper-intense EM field breaking down to electron-positron pairs), with the antiquarks dressing your pulled quarks to form mesons, and the quarks combining with other emergent quark-antiquark pairs to form ("hadronize to") a spray of hadrons (jets). This is what happens in a hadronic collision, in a way, even though you *do have* quark-antiquark pairs around: they do not modify this qualitatively.

But the [***virtual*** quark-antiquark pairs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_particle) you have in a hadron are incessantly roiling and bubbling into and out of the (QCD) vacuum all the time: one yoctosecond you see the pair, and the next you don't. So you can't think of the hadron as a jar full of a fixed number of marbles in it.

This ["sea"](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/312599/sea-quark-parton-annihilation) of quark-antiquark pairs can be measured quite well in scattering experiments, and features of them and their parent/grave gluons determined. They modify asymptotic freedom (the force property that makes the gluon field grow, above), and chiral symmetry breaking, the feature that gives a baryon and a meson its mass.

These pairs are co-equal partners with the gluons and your initial ["valence"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parton_(particle_physics)) quarks in putting the strong interaction dynamics together.